# How do you add a path to PYTHONPATH in a Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, path

How do you add a path to `PYTHONPATH` in a Dockerfile? So that when the container is run it has the correct `PYTHONPATH`? I'm completely new to Docker.

I've added `ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/control"` to the Dockerfile as I want to add the directory `/control` to `PYTHONPATH`.

When I access the container's bash with `docker exec -it trusting_spence bash` and open python and run the commands below the directory `control` is not on the list.

`import sys print(sys.path)`

```
FROM python:2
RUN pip install requests pymongo

RUN mkdir control

COPY control_file/ /control

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/control"

CMD ["python","control/control_file/job.py"]
```

Answer (score 151):

Just add an `ENV` entry in your `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/your/custom/path"
```

Or set `PYTHONPATH` in your startup script.

Comment: I tried your suggestion without success, I've edited my original post to include my steps. Could you suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try it with the typo fixed in the string? "${PYTHONPATH}:/your/custom/path"

Comment: for one reason or another, this is still just overwriting my PYTHONPATH. Additionally, while this is modifying the ENV variable, my path according to  
`python -c "import sys; for p in sys.path: print(p)"` is still unchanged, containing only the old (seemingly overwritten) PYTHONPATH, which none of the changes

Comment: Somebody hand this guy a medal. Thank you so much. Worked like a charm. :)

Comment: The answer is correct, it's probably not working for some people because your're using the wrong path. if your module is named "mymodule" and it located at /src/mymodule then you should have: ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/src"

Answer (score 15):

You're setting the python path correctly, but your command is not being run by a shell, so the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` is not considered.

chang your `CMD` from "exec" form to "shell" form:

`CMD python control/control_file/job.py`

---

From the [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> Note: Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For example, CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or execute a shell directly, for example: CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME" ]. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment variable expansion, not docker.

Answer (score 4):

Do it in a much simpler way. Add the python path in your .env file as a line in this way.

`PYTHONPATH=/app/project_source/`