# ModuleNotFoundError on worker when attempting to import local module #222

Tags: python, dask-kubernetes

I am getting a `ModuleNotFound` error on the worker Pods when attempting to import a local module.  I'm able to import without issue on the master node.  The master and workers are using the exact same image.

The working dir on the image is organized as follows:

```
WorkDIR/
       TheNotebook.ipynb
       MyModule/
                __init__.py
                myModule.py
```

The notebook is similar to

```py
from MyModule import workerFunc

fut = daskClient.submit(workerFunc,*workerArgs);
fut.result()
```

which yields:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/client.py in result(self, timeout)
    222         if self.status == "error":
    223             typ, exc, tb = result
--> 224             raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
    225         elif self.status == "cancelled":
    226             raise result

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/distributed/protocol/pickle.py in loads()
     57 def loads(x):
     58     try:
---> 59         return pickle.loads(x)
     60     except Exception:
     61         logger.info("Failed to deserialize %s", x[:10000], exc_info=True)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named MyModule
```

I don't "install" the module in the docker image, I'm just assuming the working directory on the worker pod is the same as the WORKDIR on the docker image.  Is this incorrect?  Do I need to create a `setup.py` and install `MyModule`?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be interesting to see if there is a difference when you run `import sys; print(sys.path)` on the master node and on the worker pods.

Comment: Oh how Interesting!  On the worker, the path does not contain the empty string (''), i.e does not contain the current directory.  Is the recommended course of action setting the PYTHONPATH docker var to include '' , or is something else preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you do not have the current directory set in your `PYTHONPATH` on your workers.

You'll need to do something like this in your `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH ".:${PYTHONPATH}"
```

This will check the current directory for modules before checking others in your path. Therefore it can also be used to override installed libraries.

See [How do you add a path to PYTHONPATH in a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631146/how-do-you-add-a-path-to-pythonpath-in-a-dockerfile) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Jacob guided me to an answer.  The './' directory isn't being added to the path on the worker.  To fix this problem, I simply added the following line to my Dockerfile.

```
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:./"
```