# ModuleNotFoundError in Docker

Tags: python, dockerfile

I have imported my entire project into docker, and I am getting a

> ModuleNotFoundError

from one of the modules I have created.

```
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /workspace/
COPY . /workspace/
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --deploy --ignore-pipfile
#EXPOSE 8000
#CMD ["pipenv", "run", "python", "/workspace/bin/web.py"]
```

I tried looking around for answers, but I cannot seem to get it working.

commands:

```
docker build -t atletico .
docker run -p 8000:8000 atletico
```

Docker Build:
https://pastebin.com/FXMrY2En

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspace/bin/web.py", line 3, in <module>
    from bin.setup import setup_app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bin'
```

A copy of my directory:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── README.md
├── bin
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── web.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── setup.py
│   └── web.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── frio
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
│   ├── app_events.py
│   └── config.py
├── routes
│   ├── __init__.py
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=test_db
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  web:
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/workspace
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    command: "pipenv run python /workspace/bin/web.py"
```

Comment: can you share the logs of `docker build`

Comment: I added the build, I couldn't add it directly because of some code limit that stackoverflow implemented. Docker Build: https://pastebin.com/FXMrY2En

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?  Is the required library listed in your `Pipfile`?

Comment: Yes the Pipfile and the Pipfile.lock is in the directory. I am getting a ModuleNotFoundError. But this file is located in the same directory as the caller.

Comment: is the `bin` folder contains `__init__.py` file?

Comment: Yes my bin folder does contain a `__init__.py`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So I finally fixed the issue. For those who may be wondering how was it that I fixed it. You need to define a `PYTHONPATH` environment variable either in the `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml`.

Comment: For those who need help to define it => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631146/how-do-you-add-a-path-to-pythonpath-in-a-dockerfile

Comment: I was able to define "ENV PYTHONPATH=." in my dockerfile.

Answer (score 3):

[docker-compose.yml modified part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sc1dp.png)

I had the same issue, then it works after adding the `PYTHONPATH=/workspace` into docker-compose.yml like in the example photo.
In my case, it works without `__init__.py` as well.