# Docker environment/PythonPath issue

Tags: docker, web-development-server

I'm creating the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:current-alpine as builder
COPY /webapp/public/* public/
COPY /webapp/src/* src/
COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
ENV PYTHONPATH="/webapp"
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm","start"]

EXPOSE 80
```

based on this [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eu1UC.png).

I'm getting the following output from docker logs: /src/App.js Module not found: Can't resolve './Configure/ConfigurationPage' in '/src'. Configuration page is a file located [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCCA2.png).

Notice this line in my dockerfile:

```
ENV PYTHONPATH="/webapp"
```

I added this line based on a post with someone having a similar issue:
[ModuleNotFoundError in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60792029/modulenotfounderror-in-docker).
As per the post, this issue most likely has to do with the environment not being configured correctly, specifically ENV PYTHONPATH not being correctly defined. The ENV PYTHONPATH="/webapp" line in my Dockerfile didn't fix the issue. What else can I try to fix this?

Comment: You might `docker run --rm your-image ls ./src` to see what actually got copied into the image.  Setting `$PYTHONPATH` only makes a difference for Python applications, not Javascript/Node programs, and you can delete this variable.

Comment: @DavidMaze ConfigurationPage is listed when i run ```docker run --rm your-image ls ./src```