# ModuleNotFoundError and import errors in Docker container

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

When importing python modules locally, I am able to successfully do so, however I'm having difficulty doing so when dockerising the app. It seems as though I get the opposite behaviour locally to how I get in the docker app... any thoughts?

I have the following directory structure

```
| app
|      |api.py
|      |settings.py
| tests
|      |test_api.py
```

In api.py, I import settings by:
`from app import settings`
In test_api.py I import app.py by: `from app import api`.

Locally, everything works fine. When I try to dockerize this API using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine

RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile /usr/src/
WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY app /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

CMD ["python", "api.py"]
```

The docker image builds successfully, however upon running the container, I get the following error:

```
File "api.py", line 4, in <module>
from app import settings
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

If I change how I import in api.py, to `import settings`, I get errors locally, but the docker container works perfectly. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the PythonPath, any thoughts on how I can resolve this?

Comment: i believe that if you try to use it as a module, i'd recommend you to create a file __init__.py on the app folder... it is required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages.(can just be an empty file)

Comment: I've answered the question in one of the responses below after having seen some other posts online and combining them with the answer from @stefan below.

Answer (score 8):

I've just come across another thread on StackOverflow which seems to have resolved my issue. I can leave the import statements as I indicated above in my question, and by setting the PYTHONPATH in the docker container correctly, I am able to get the imports working correctly in docker.

[How do you add a path to PYTHONPATH in a Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631146/how-do-you-add-a-path-to-pythonpath-in-a-dockerfile)

My updated (working) Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine

RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile /usr/src/
WORKDIR /usr/src
RUN pipenv lock --requirements > requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY app /usr/src/app

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/src/app"

CMD ["python", "app/api.py"]
```

Comment: How to write when I have multiple such apps like app1, app2, app3, etc:
`
| app1
|      |api.py
|      |settings.py
|app2
|      |x.py
|      |y.py
|app3
|      |alpha.py
| tests
|      |test_api.py
`

Answer (score 1):

Your working directory is /usr/src/app and the import statement tries to find the directory "app". If you change your working directory to /usr/src/.

Alternatively you can import the settings directly via:

```
import settings
```

instead of

```
from app import settings
```

Comment: Changing the WORKDIR to usr/src doesn't solve the problem as is I do that, it can't find api.py. If I then have the CMD["python", "app/api.py"], I get exactly the same problem.

Using the import settings as opposed to from app import settings works in the docker container, but not locally.

Comment: Looks like I need the WORKDIR to /usr/src as well as some other bits which I'll add in a separate post.

Comment: @AnishPatel from where do you start your api.py locally? if its from outside app you could use "from . import settings"

Answer (score -1):

You should use just

```
import settings
```

since, "api.py" & "settings.py" both are in app folder.

Comment: This works for the docker container, but then I get local issues... perhaps some local python path stuff? I'm using Pipenv which potentially complicates matters.

Comment: I am not getting your question. Are you trying to say that you are doing the same project on docker & also locally?

Comment: what is file hierachy for local project?

Comment: The file hierarchy is the same locally as in the docker container. The solution is above, I've posted it. Thanks for looking.