# How to configure a PYTHONPATH env variable in the Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-import

I am modifying the [Machine Learning Inference](https://github.com/debnsuma/MLInference-Lambda-EFS)  to perform inference using my trained model and to this it is need to import a set of modules. So the project tree is now:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── __init__.py
├── app.py
├── requirements.txt
**
└── maskrcnn
    ├── config.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── m_rcnn.py
    ├── visualize.py
    ├── mask_rcnn_coco.h5
    └── model.py
**
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Pull the base image with python 3.8 as a runtime for your Lambda
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8

# Copy the earlier created requirements.txt file to the container
COPY requirements.txt ./

# Install the python requirements from requirements.txt
RUN python3.8 -m pip install -r requirements.txt 

# Create the model directory for mounting the EFS 
RUN mkdir -p /mnt/ml

# Copy the earlier created app.py file to the container
COPY app.py ./
COPY maskrcnn/ ./maskrcnn


# Set the CMD to your handler
CMD ["app.lambda_handler"]
```

To import the python modules in `app.py` I used the following command line:

```
from maskrcnn.m_rcnn import *
from maskrcnn.visualize import random_colors, get_mask_contours, draw_mask
```

When running my docker image, I get an import error:

```
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'maskrcnn'", 

"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}
```

---

My other problem is that in the module `m_rcnn.py` the file `mask_rcnn_coco.h5` is accessed to do some procedures.

m_rcnn.py:

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath("/maskrcnn")


# Local path to trained weights file
COCO_MODEL_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "mask_rcnn_coco.h5")
```

Because of this code I am getting the following error:

```
{"errorMessage": "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 

'/maskrcnn/mask_rcnn_coco.h5'", "errorType": "FileNotFoundError"},
```

Comment: Not sure, how your modules `app` and `maskrcnn` are imported. Can you add the import section of `app.py` to the question?

Comment: I already added this information, to import I used `from maskrcnn.m_rcnn import *`. If I just run the `app.py` function I can import maskrcnn.  The problem occurs when I build the project, using: `sam build --use-container`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631146/how-do-you-add-a-path-to-pythonpath-in-a-dockerfile

Comment: Your Dockerfile only copy `app.py`,  but not copy `maskrcnn`, thus it failed to find the module `maskrcnn` .  For your case,   you can add `ENV PYTHONPATH=.:$PYTHONPATH` into Dockerfile to tell python to search python module from work dir where `app.py` and `maskrcnn` folder resides.

Comment: I declared the following in my dockerfile 
`ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/maskrcnn"`, but it didn't work, I also tried to use the full path which is: "/my-ml-project/ml-inference/maskrcnn".  It still gives the same error.

Comment: I'm not sure there's really any reason to modify `PYTHONPATH` for a Docker image, as you already have pretty much complete control over the local file system. Just install things where Python will already look for packages.

Comment: @chepner I tried to do what you said, delete the maskrcnn folder and put my modules in the same folder as `app.py` and tried to import using `from m_rcnn import *`. But it still gives the same error.

Comment: Don't put them in the same directory as `app.py`. Put them where other packages installed by `pip` would be stored. (Better yet, package your code so that `maskrcnn` itself is a proper package that `pip install -r requirements` can install.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the Python module `maskrcnn` from your lokal working directory, you have to copy it into the Docker image. Adding a COPY statement for `maskrcnn/*` could solve the issue:

```
# Dockerfile

# Copy the earlier created app.py file to the container
COPY app.py ./
COPY maskrcnn/ ./maskrcnn
```

And please remove the line `ENV PYTHONPATH...`. I don't see any indication to mess around with PYTHONPATH.

Comment: This 100% is the problem. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75663650/2954547) is only valid if you actually put the `maskrcnn` directory in the image!

Comment: @shadowtalker My point is __do not manipulate PYTHONPATH__ at all - I couldn't read that so clearly from your answer yet.

Comment: My answer focuses on explaining how to use `PYTHONPATH` _correctly_, and the conclusion is the same: you shouldn't need to use it here. However I am not of the same opinion that you should never mess with it, but you should know how it works before doing so.

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg I implemented your solution and it worked. But, another problem has arisen, in `m_rcnn.py` module it is download weights from `mask_rcnn_coco.h5` file. And although I have copied `maskrcnn` module into dockerI am getting the following error: `No such file or directory: '/maskrcnn/mask_rcnn_coco.h5`. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem that has appeared?

Comment: `directory: '/maskrcnn/mask_rcnn_coco.h5` looks like an absoulute path on Unix. I guess the import should use a relative path like `'./maskrcnn/mask_rcnn_coco.h5`. Do you find the source code line producing this error?

Comment: @KonstantinA.Magg I used `./maskrcnn/mask_rcnn_coco.h5` and it worked, thanks! As I edited the question if you want it would be interesting to put this additional information in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`PYTHONPATH` tells Python where to look for modules and packages.

The `/maskrcnn` directory *is itself a package* due to the presence of the `__init__.py` file.

Therefore, adding `./maskrcnn` to `PYTHONPATH` accomplishes nothing! You need the *parent directory* of `maskrcnn` added to the Python search path, which is just the current directory `.`, which is usually added to the Python search path by default.

Furthermore, you added the directory `/maskrcnn` to `PYTHONPATH`, and *not* `./maskrcnn`. As far as I can tell from the Dockerfile, the former directory doesn't even exist.

As per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75663954/2954547), all this is moot anyway because you forgot to copy the `maskrcnn` directory in to the image! <strike>I actually don't know the cause of the error as-written; that will require further debugging. But</strike> Once you fix that problem, this Dockerfile *should* work as-is if you simply remove the `ENV PYTHONPATH` directive.

If that still doesn't work, then possibly `.` is *not* in the package search path, so try `ENV PYTHONPATH "."` to ensure that it is added.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to add this lines before importing `maskrcnn`:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).parents[0]))

from maskrcnn.m_rcnn import *
from maskrcnn.visualize import random_colors, get_mask_contours, draw_mask
```

This way, the module maskrcnn will be searched at the same level as app.py so the imports should work correctly.

Comment: I don't know that this answer deserves a downvote, because it's a valid alternative solution in the case of deploying an "app" like this with a known directory structure. However it also doesn't really answer the question, and the caveat (of being sensitive to directory structure) should be stated explicitly.